# How to store each line while using SAX parcer to parse a given xml file

Tags: java, xml, saxparser

I am looking forward to store each line a validate a specific condition while parsing the XML file using SAX parser in Java.

**Issue:** when I convert the character [] to a new string with Characters(...) method of the parser, I am not getting the line text properly.

**Expected:** Need to store a line of XML file inside a String variable.

**Code:**

```
public void characters(char[] arg0, int arg1, int arg2) throws SAXException {
if (text) {
String str = new String(arg0,arg1,arg2);
System.out.println(str.trim());
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

The number one mistake people make with SAX is that they fail to realize that the XML parser is free to break up text nodes anywhere it likes and make multiple calls on the characters() callback. You need to accumulate these values until the end of the text node, marked by the next non-characters event, e.g. a call on startElement or endElement.

You talk of "lines" of text, but don't expect the XML parser to pass the text across one line at a time. (Some parsers might: the spec allows it but doesn't require it.)

Answer (score 0):

You need an [`ignorableWhitespace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler.html#ignorableWhitespace%28char%5b%5d,%20int,%20int%29) callback.

But your objective is questionable. XML doesn't consist of lines, it consists of elements and attributes.

Comment: I am talking about text contained within a particular tag. In my case, the text tag has a huge volume of text and I intend to store all each line in String

Answer (score 0):

Try this! Use a `LinkedList` to store the tag names at every `startElement()` and remove the last element using `pollLast()` at every `endElement()`. Use `String.trim()` to get the data from `characters()`. So everytime the `characters()` function returns some actual data (Use `String.length()!=0`) you can associate it with the last element (`peekLast()`) in the `LinkedList`

Then you can choose to `append()` it